# Apps feel right?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

We're establishing a software development house and we came up with the name:

> Apps feel right

with the meaning, applications that feel right to use.

I can't pinpoint the reason but something doesn't feel right in this name. We're afraid that the name can be understood outside of it's intended meaning like "applications (as if they have feelings) feel alright".

I've repeated this so many times now, the words lost the meaning for me.

Does the name reflects the intend? If not, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and say it: as a native English speaker, this name is just weird and awkward. You'll spend most of your time explaining the name to customers instead of writing cool software. I vote no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding views on naming are specified as unacceptable on ELU.

Comment: He is asking why it sounds grammatically awkward. You could always do "feel good apps".

Comment: Interestingly when we don't use this plural, it doesn't sound that awkward. 

"app feels right"

since you can use this in the sentence,

"After the latest update, this app feels right"

Is it something about using it plural? Or is it because the subject of the feeling is generally a feature rather than the whole app. 

"The scrolling of the user list, doesn't feel right"

By the way I'm sorry if you think this question doesn't belong to the platform, if that's the case please close the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names are proper nouns. At the very least, they need to function grammatically as nouns. Although product / company names are automatically treated as nouns, ‘Apps Feel Right’ doesn’t sound like a name because it isn’t a noun phrase when read as an English expression. It is a proposition, something you can assign a truth value to (the proposition is *true* or *false*).

You can change it to a noun phrase by reordering the words to something like **Feel-right Apps**, which is a noun phrase headed by the noun *apps*.

Comment: I think **FeelGood Apps** works even better. I would have added it as a separate answer, but I only thought of it because of your own answer.